# Best approach for containing content?

Tags: css

Here's my scenario.

1. I have a WOW slider with images fixed at 1360px.
2. I have a Table with width set at 100%

My problem surfaces at resolutions above 1360px because my table contents grow wider than the image slider and it looks awful. I want the table contents to fill the width of the screen at lower resolutions but not resize above 1360px.

Is there a way to achieve this with CSS? I don't know what else to try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Apply `max-width:1360px` to the table, either through the CSS styling page like

```
#tableId {
  width:100%;
  max-width:1360px;
}
```

or put it in the `<table>` tag itself (not recommended if you have a stylesheet)

```
<table style='width=100%; max-width:1360px'>
```

Comment: OMG, Zeaklous it worked. I had to use the style inside the table tag though, the other methods you and KBA suggested didn't work for me but I am a very happy camper right now. Thanks a gazillion times over dude.

Comment: That likely means that there is something else in the stylesheet overriding it to start. If you find that an answer has satisfactorily answered your question you can click the check mark next to the answer to mark it as correct and show your question has been answered

Comment: Zeaklous, the table tag stopped working above 1280px but I split it up into two sections that work without a problem now it looks like this:

width="100%" style="max-width: 1360px;"

Answer (score 0):

You're looking for [`max-width`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/max-width).

```
#table {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 1360px;
}
```

Using the above, the table will take up a 100% of the horizontal screen, but never more than 1360px.

Comment: kba, wow thank you for replying to my thread you and Keaklous rock big time you guys get a BIG HIGH 5.

Comment: kba, I don't think I set things up correctly in the CSS section that's probably why your code didn't work for me. I know little about CSS but I'm learning much more in this forum.

Comment: `#table` should be the ID of your table prefixed with `#` to symbolise that it's an ID, not a tag name. The above code works, assuming I understand your question properly.